# Why ss -e doesn't show uid?

Tags: ss

I have a debian VM, here the info:

```
las@Client:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
```

When I type `ss -nte` I expect to see the uid of the process that uses the socket because of the `-e` option, but it doesn't appear and I can't figure it out why. Here's the output:

```
las@Client:~$ ss -nte
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                    Local Address:Port                      Peer Address:Port 
ESTAB       0      176                      192.168.56.201:22                        192.168.56.1:50468  timer:(on,204ms,0) ino:12286 sk:ffff88000e7f3140 <->
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ss`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ss.8) command (any version) will display an *uid* only if it's not zero. Here's the [source for the Debian 8 jessie version](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/iproute2/-/blob/debian/3.16.0-2/misc/ss.c#L1432):

```
    if (show_details) {
        if (s.uid)
            printf(" uid:%u", (unsigned)s.uid);
        printf(" ino:%u", s.ino);
        printf(" sk:%llx", s.sk);
        if (opt[0])
            printf(" opt:\"%s\"", opt);
    }
```

The test `if (s.uid)` makes it not display the information each time the socket owner's uid value is `0`.

Additional tests (but using kernel 5.6 and a matching `ss` from *iproute2* 5.6.0), show that indeed a normal user can know the owner's *uid* of an other socket even if not owned by itself. So the absence of the `uid:` entry can mean only two things: owned by the *root* user, or owned by the kernel (which is different, but can't be distinguished here).

In your case, as the *sshd* daemon is running as *root*, all TCP sockets related to it will be owned by *root*, even if *sshd* grants a non-root login. The user login granted by *sshd* is not connected to any TCP socket: it's connected to the *sshd* daemon (or a separate instance of it) through master/slave [PTYs](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/pty.7) or else with [pipes](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/pipe.7). So `ss` can't be used to match a TCP connection to a user locally logged in through incoming *ssh*.

Comment: To add a minor detail that I hope won't lower explanation: the sshd process parent to the login shell or command does belong to the user and does have the TCP socket. But it's a duplicate copy of the original socket (still opened by the root sshd process parent to this sshd), with same  pseudo-filesystem *sockfs*'s inode, which was initially opened as uid 0.